# missing _ctypes and without yum and pkg

Tags: python, python-3.x, freebsd

I was trying to install python 3.7.4 on a freebsd machine. 
At the end of `make install` the error popped out.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

Libffi is installed by source and its prefix was set to `$HOME/lib/libffi`

Attempt 1. I've tried installing [cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython), and it installed setuptools successfully at the end of `make install`. Then when I was installing numpy by source, The same error appeared.

So I deleted cpython and tried to install the regular one again.

Attempt 2. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55867213/building-python3-7-3-from-source-missing-ctypes) I added the some stuffs while doing `./configure`. The full command was:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=$HOME/programs/python --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I $HOME/lib/libffi/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include"
```

but the same error popped out at the end of `make install`

Attempt 3. I've tried to force install an anaconda on it, but it didn't work.

Side note 1: yum and did not exist on the machine, and I don't have the root access.

Side note 2: I've deleted every `-fprofile-correction` in `Makefile`, since the machine doesn't recognize it.

Side note 3: this is found near the end of `make`:

```
Python build finished successfully!
(...)
Failed to build these modules:
_ctypes
```

Comment: You have to go back in the log, and check why *\_ctypes* failed to build (probably it couldn't find the *libffi* library at link time?).

Comment: The log file did not contain the reason. The only thing associated is `building '_ctypes_test'`, and no error message was shown.

Comment: I'd rather install it using packages. Command "sudo pkg install python37" will install python-3.7.4  with zero problems.
In general installation from the source is the last resort when software  cannot be found in packages or ports.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't contain pkg, either. The build of yum and pkg both failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost always a mistake for a FreeBSD user to build a software package, that's already been officially ported to the OS, himself.

What you should do instead is:

```
    cd /usr/ports/lang/python37
    make install clean
```

Comment: However, the files there only contains python23~python25. is there a way to update that?

Comment: Your ports-collection is _severely_ out of date -- the [lang/python37](https://www.freshports.org/lang/python37) port is more than a year old. Refresh the `/usr/ports/` using one of [these methods](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html) and try again.