# Building Python3.9.2 from source missing '_ctypes'

Tags: python, libffi

I have a similar issue to the one I was able to solve in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55867213/building-python3-7-3-from-source-missing-ctypes), when building Python3.9.2 in docker container the build finish successfully but ctypes is missing

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'`

Trying the same method in the above post did not worked, I even tried to install the latest libffi-3.3 with the same results, all the libffi headers and libs are in place.

It seems that only the `_ctypes_test` shared object was build.

```
root@74f1b419ddd8:/# find / -name _ctypes*
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ctypes_test.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

I found some tickets regarding this but nothing worked for me:

- https://bugs.python.org/issue34823
- https://bugs.python.org/issue14527
- https://bugs.python.org/issue30090

Any idea how I can make it work for the latest Python 3.9?

**Update:**
Tested on Python 3.7.10 & 3.8.8 and it seems to work fine so it probably something that changed on 3.9.*

**Update2:**
I took the `_ctypes.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` file from a prebuilt docker `pyhton:3.9.2-slim` and put it in my container at `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ctypes_test.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and it worked, `import ctypes` did not raised this error (I had to build python with `libffi-3.2.1` and not `3.3`).
Why I can't get `make` to build `_ctypes`?

Comment: Maybe it is having a hard time finding libffi?

Comment: Probably but I can’t get the build to find it

Comment: Maybe you could use `Modules/Setup.local`? I got it to work with this in `Setup.local`:
`CTYPES_FLAGS=-DHAVE_FFI_PREP_CIF_VAR=1 -DHAVE_FFI_PREP_CLOSURE_LOC=1 -DHAVE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC=1\n
_ctypes _ctypes/_ctypes.c _ctypes/callbacks.c _ctypes/callproc.c _ctypes/cfield.c _ctypes/stgdict.c $(CTYPES_FLAGS)\n
_ctypes_test _ctypes/_ctypes_test.c
`

Comment: Probably you'll get linker errors due to missing libffi, but they are more helpful than it just silently not including ctypes.